# Customizing DevExpress MVC Dashboard Style Sheet using ThemeBuilder

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I am trying to add a custom stylesheet built using the DevExtreme ThemeBuilder (https://devexpress.github.io/ThemeBuilder/)

I have found the following code but it does not allow a custom stylesheet.

```
@Html.DevExpress().StyleSheets(styles => styles.AddDashboard(settings => settings.ColorScheme("dark.compact")))
```

How to implement this? Any support article please?

Component : DevExpress MVC Dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, DevExtreme ThemeBuilder (https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Themes_and_Styles/ThemeBuilder/) is only applicable to create a custom theme for DevExtreme components, so you can't use it in this case.